# Use Variable from Useform in different Module

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I couldn't quite find what I'm looking for but maybe you can help me anyway.

My problem is that I have a userform where the user has to make an input. I want to store that input and use it later in a different module i.e. paste it into a cell. The simple solution should be to just make it a public variable, but for some reason it won't work. Here is the code I tried to use:

**Userform**:

```
Option Explicit

Public VarBezeichnungReifenliste As String

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    VarBezeichnungReifenliste = TextBox1.Value
    Call Übertragen

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

**Module**:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Übertragen()

  Worksheets("XY").Cells(1, 1).Value = VarBezeichnungReifenliste

End Sub
```

The error message says the variable is not declared (`VarBezeichnungReifenliste`) so i guess I didn't declare it publicly enough?

The userform itself is opened via a simple button on the worksheet using `Userform1.Show`. So nothing fancy here.

Comment: Move `Public VarBezeichnungReifenliste As String` to top of the other sub (if it's in a normal module).

Comment: Also just noticed - your `Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()` is inside the `Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()` procedure.  It shouldn't compile with an `Expected End Sub` error.  Move the second `End Sub` to above `Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()`.

Comment: Sorry - meant move it to the top of the other _module_ not _sub_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Publicly Enough

### Solution1

**UserForm1**:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    VarBezeichnungReifenliste = TextBox1.Value
    Module1.Übertragen
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

**Module1**:

```
Option Explicit

Public VarBezeichnungReifenliste As String

Sub Übertragen()
    Worksheets("XY").Cells(1, 1).Value = VarBezeichnungReifenliste
End Sub
```

**Conclusion**

Just move the variable declaration

```
Public VarBezeichnungReifenliste As String
```

to a 'normal' module.

### Solution2

**UserForm1**:

```
Option Explicit

Public VarBezeichnungReifenliste As String

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    VarBezeichnungReifenliste = TextBox1.Value
    Module1.Übertragen
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

**Module1**:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Übertragen()
    Worksheets("XY").Cells(1, 1).Value = UserForm1.VarBezeichnungReifenliste
    Worksheets("XY").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

**Conclusion**

Just use

```
Worksheets("XY").Cells(1, 1).Value = UserForm1.VarBezeichnungReifenliste
```

instead of

```
Worksheets("XY").Cells(1, 1).Value = VarBezeichnungReifenliste
```

in Module1.

### Solution3

**UserForm1**:

```
Option Explicit

Public VarBezeichnungReifenliste As String

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    VarBezeichnungReifenliste = TextBox1.Value
    Übertragen
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Sub Übertragen()
    Worksheets("XY").Cells(1, 1).Value = VarBezeichnungReifenliste
End Sub
```

**Conclusion**

Move everything into UserForm1.

Answer (score 0):

VBA is weird about storing variables over the long-term. As a general rule of thumb, if you're able to interact with Excel workbooks in between a variable being saved and when you need to get the value, you can't count on that variable still holding its value.

The safest way to get around this is to just store your value in a cell of a hidden worksheet, and read it from there when you need it.

Comment: I'd disagree with that.  It's a case of knowing when you're variables will go out of scope.  If you want to save values between closing and reopening the workbook then store them on a hidden sheet (there's also some other way that Chip Pearson explains on his site, but can't remember it now).

Comment: I'm looking for the documentation on it, but I'm pretty sure all variables declared in a form are `Private` so aren't available to other modules.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Open a VBA module, set a public module-level variable to a value, save the workbook, then view the value of your variable. When I do this, the value is reset. It's not just opening or closing a workbook that'll reset variables, just saving a workbook will do it too. I believe auto-save also resets it, which is why you can't rely on variables holding their values long-term.

Comment: It depends on the scope & lifetime of the variable.  In `ThisWorkbook` add `Public MyVar As String` at the top of the module, in the `Workbook_Open` event set a value to `MyVar`, in the `AfterSave` event add a msgbox that displays the value of `MyVar` - the value is still there after a save. [Scope Of Variables And Procedures](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx) & [Lifetime of Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-the-lifetime-of-variables)

Comment: Further citation: *"Public procedures, variables, and constants defined in other than standard or class modules, such as form modules or report modules, are not available to referencing projects, because these modules are private to the project in which they reside."*
See [Understanding scope and visibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility)